# Add Solana Network to Wallet Connect Web package

Tags: solana, wallet-connect

Following this documentation:

https://docs.walletconnect.com/web3modal/react/about

I installed the package in a React app,

`npm install @web3modal/ethers5 ethers@5.7.2`

After this I was able to connect a Phantom wallet from my browser, but only on Ethereum, I don't know how to add Solana to the chains

```
// 5. Create a Web3Modal instance
createWeb3Modal({
  ethersConfig,
  chains: [mainnet],
  projectId,
  enableAnalytics: true, // Optional - defaults to your Cloud configuration
});
```

How do I add Solana? The current setup only has Ethereum.

```
// 2. Set chains
const mainnet = {
  chainId: 1,
  name: "Ethereum",
  currency: "ETH",
  explorerUrl: "https://etherscan.io",
  rpcUrl: "https://cloudflare-eth.com",
};
```